# How to best write a SQL SPROC to clone table rows but changing select fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have the following table

```
fID Field1  Field2
1   a       dennis
1   f       mac 
2   j       clownbaby
1   k       charlie
3   t       frank
7   d       dee
```

and I want to take all the rows with 1 in the first column and insert them in the same table with a number I could pick as an argument to my stored procedure.
So that if I called my stored procedure as rowClone(1,8) I would end up with a table with

```
fID Field1  Field2
1   a       dennis
1   f       mac 
2   j       clownbaby
1   k       charlie
3   t       frank
7   d       dee
8   a       dennis
8   f       mac
8   k       charlie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create Procedure RowClone(@fIDToClone int, @newFID int)
As
Insert Table(fID, Field1, Field2)
Select @newFID, Field1, Field2
From Table
Where fID = @fIDToClone
```

You will probably want to add an additional check that ensures that the routine does not create duplicates. However, you did not mention what unique keys exist on the table.